# Elementary description for $\mathbb{P}^1\times X$ and rational equivalence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, schubert-calculus

In order to define the chow group of a variety $X$ one considers cycles modulo rational equivalence where two cycles $A_0, A_1\in Z(X)$ are called rationally equivalent if there exists a cycle on $\mathbb{P}^1\times X$ whose restriction to $\{t_0\}\times X$ and $\{t_1\}\times X$ are $A_0, A_1$ respectively.

I want to use this definition to give some intuition for the behaviour of the cohomology ring in Schubert calculus. This means that the variety $X$ is simply the Grassmannian. Is it possible in this restricted context to describe $\mathbb{P}^1\times X$ and rational equivalence without having to introduce the machinery of schemes? I suspect that there may be some relation to Segre varieties but am not sure I truly understand what $\mathbb{P}^1\times X$ means.

Comment: Maybe this is useful: http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/oldwebpages/Math683Fall2013/Product.pdf

Comment: But yes, if X lies in some projective space $\mathbb{P}^N$ (using the Plucker embedding probably), then you can realize $\mathbb{P}^1 \times X$ as a projective variety via the Segre embedding. I think nothing here should require schemes?

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer, $\mathbb{P}^1 \times X$ is a subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^N$ equipped with the Segre structure. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it so that others can find this too in the future.